# IEEE 802.3 vs IEEE 802.11

Tags: lan, wifi, osi

Can someone please explain to me the difference in the OSI Model between the 802.3 and 802.11 protocols?

As far as I understand they differ only in the MAC and PHY Layer. Is this accurate?

Are the remaining layers identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the IEEE 802.3 and IEEE 802.11 are standards that address the MAC and PHY layers. Anything above those layers remain agnostic from them (MAC & PHY layers).